# How to remove dependencies from android project using Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-studio-2.2

i'm using android studio as IDE for my application developpement 
and i'm not sure about the fact that when i remove a dependency from my dependencies list in gradle all the related file are going to be remover or i have to remove all of them manually

did any one can help 
Thanks

Comment: Which file is being removed?

Answer (score 4):

You can go to `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies` and remove any dependency graphically, or you can just remove it form `build.gradle` file.

> If you project is **using** the dependency, you are currently removing, you will have to update that and remove any references to the dependency before building.

Comment: You can't do it graphically, because there is no remove button – only an add button. Editing the build.gradle file works though.

Comment: I see a lot of dependencies in my project (project structure -> dependencies -> all modules) which are not added via build.gradle (module).

How can I verify that these are not used somewhere and how to delete them? 
In .idea\libraries I see the relevant xml file but don't find any sources or binaries which are listed there. No mention of the libraries in the source code is found.

Is it safe to just delete the xml files in the .idea\libraries folder?